# How can I solve "Forge IP Addresses: We are upgrading our servers! If you use IP whitelisting, please add our new addresses" on the forge laravel?

Tags: laravel, ssh, laravel-5.3, forge, laravel-forge

When I access laravel forge (https://forge.laravel.com), there exist warning like this :

```
Forge IP Addresses: We are upgrading our servers! If you use IP whitelisting, please add our new addresses: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.
```

Seems It will add new address. But i'm still confused to add it

Whether it is added in digital ocean via ssh?

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why this question is downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what yuou have configured security wise, you'll likely need to add new firewall rules for the ip addresses. As it says, if you've whitelisted forge servers anywhere you'll have to do the same for these.

You may have a whitelist defined through your webserver as well.

Comment: How do I add it? Whether it is added in digital ocean via ssh?

Comment: I would assume you can add through your digital ocean account. I'm not certain though, I don't host through them. AWS, for example, you login and set it under ec2.